# How do I "overload" websocket?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, websocket

In the instructions on this page:

https://github.com/FreakDev/PhoneGap-Android-HTML5-WebSocket

It states: in your javascript, create a new WebSocket, and overload its method 'onmessage', 'onopen', 'onerror', 'onclick';

What does this mean?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at their [javascript](https://github.com/FreakDev/PhoneGap-Android-HTML5-WebSocket/blob/master/js/websocket.js) file, you can see they set:

```
// listener to overload
this.onopen = null;
this.onmessage = null;
this.onerror = null;
this.onclose = null;
```

You should set those to be implementations you want to be called.  E.g.

```
their_object.onopen = function (openObject) {
   // Your code here.
}
```